# benefits of Fused-Provider with BALANCED_POWER over Network-Provider

Tags: android, networking, location, location-provider

If I understand correctly fused provider with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` is using network provider.

So what are the benefits of the fused provider?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't quite how the Fused provider works.  In the docs it says:

> Applications cannot specify the exact location sources, such as GPS, that are used by the LocationClient. In fact, the system may have multiple location sources (providers) running and may fuse the results from several sources into a single Location object.

According to the docs, `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` is a request for block level accuracy.  Since it's not high power this may imply network providers (wifi & cell), but there may be situations where GPS information is used as well.  Such as if the device already has a GPS location, perhaps from another app.

Further, the Fused provider uses sensor data (not network or GPS) to improve the location accuracy.  I can't say how exactly this works, but you can see that the Fused locations do tend to be more accurate.

[Android docs for details](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html).